# Meaning of "wember" in British English

Tags: british-english

As a result of a web search of items in the Huddersfield, England, area the following words "Wembers all food before use..." created uncertainty. Is this an example of a typographic error or does "wembers" have a local meaning?

*See examples in the 9th Huddersfield Crosland Hill Scout Group document ["Backwoods Cooking"](http://www.9thhuddersfieldscouts.org.uk/Scouting/Scoutcraft/Cooking/Backwoods%20Cooking%20-%20Introduction.pdf).*

Answer (score 14):

If you look at occurrences of 'embers' in the source document, several are spelled 'emberses'. 
I think these, and 'wembers' are an artefact of an imperfectly executed 'find and replace' which was supposed to change 'ash' to 'ember' and inadvertantly also changes 'ashes' to 'emberses' and 'wash' to 'wembers'.

@AndyT points out further words 'fembersion' and 'dembers' which would result from replacing 'ash' with 'ember' in 'fashion' and 'dash'.

As to why the change was executed; I would hazard that that the 9th Huddersfield version was subject to the change when someone decided that the use of 'ashes' as copied from [the Backwoods Cookbook](https://caherdavinscouts.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/backwoods_cooking.pdf) (which @JamesP linked) was inaccurate. Chambers does give **embers** as 'red hot ashes', but **ash** as 'dust or remains of anything burnt'. For clarity you would want to make sure people knew to use the glowing bits rather than the grey bits. So the change was possibly made following a critical review of the article.

Comment: It would also explain "fembersion" as meaning "fashion" and "dembers" meaning "dash".

Comment: @AndyT lol, I missed those but they do bear out the theory pretty well!

Comment: This version seems to be the original, and fits in with your theory of find and replace. https://caherdavinscouts.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/backwoods_cooking.pdf

Comment: Fascinating. Why would this search and replace have happened? By whom and why?

Comment: Cool Makes sense